# Report error on unset Twig variables

Tags: php, exception, twig

If a Twig template contains an unset variable, the behaviour depends on the `strict_variables` setting. The two options are:

1. `false` (default): Treat the variable as NULL, and continue rendering the template.
2. `true`: Throw an exception, and stop rendering the template.

Ideally, you’d use `true` in development, and `false` in production.

What I’d like, however, is a third option:

- Throw an exception (which will be picked up and reported by our normal error-handling code), but also continue rendering the Template as if the variable were NULL.

Is there any way to achieve this?

We are using Twig, but in our own environment, not the Symfony framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [custom exception listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) to handle this.  Something like;

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Twig_Error_Runtime;

class TwigExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if (!$exception instanceof Twig_Error_Runtime) {
            return;
        }

        // do whatever you need to do here
    }
}
```

Now this will catch *all* Twig runtime errors, but that will probably suffice for what you need.  I left out the dependency injection for whatever services you might need, but you get the idea.